# (py)Spark Parallelized Maximum Likelihood Calculation

Tags: python, scipy, pyspark, mle

I have two quick rookie questions on (py)Spark. I have a Dataframe as below, I want to calculate the likelihood of the 'reading' column using scipy's `multivariate_normal.pdf()`

```
rdd_dat = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(0, .12, "a"),(1, .45, "b"),(2, 1.01, "c"),(3, 1.2, "a"),
                                         (4, .76, "a"),(5, .81, "c"),(6, 1.5, "b")])
df = rdd_dat.toDF(["id", "reading", "category"])
df.show()
+---+-------+--------+
| id|reading|category|
+---+-------+--------+
|  0|   0.12|       a|
|  1|   0.45|       b|
|  2|   1.01|       c|
|  3|    1.2|       a|
|  4|   0.76|       a|
|  5|   0.81|       c|
|  6|    1.5|       b|
+---+-------+--------+
```

This is my attempt using the `UserDefinedFunction`:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

mle = UserDefinedFunction(multivariate_normal.pdf, DoubleType())
mean =1
cov=1
df_with_mle = df.withColumn("MLE", mle(df['reading']))
```

This runs without throwing an error, but when I want to look at the resulting `df_with_mle`, I get the error below:

```
df_with_mle.show()
An error occurred while calling o149.showString.
```

**1)** Any idea why I am getting this error?

**2)** If I wanted to specify the `mean` and `cov`, like: `df.withColumn("MLE", mle(df['reading'], 1, 1))`, how I can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The multivariate_normal.pdf() method from scipy is expecting to receive a series. A column from pandas dataframe is a series, but a column from a PySpark dataframe is a different kind of object (a pyspark.sql.column.Column), which Scipy doesn't know how to handle.

Also, and this won't keep your function call from running, your function definition ends without specifying the parameters - cov and mean aren't defined explicitly in the API unless they occur within the method call. Mean and Cov are just integer objects until you set them as parameters and override the defaults (mean=0, cov=1, from the scipy documentation:

```
multivariate_normal.pdf(x=df['reading'], mean=mean,cov=cov)
```